# Angular2 submit a form to the server

Tags: http, angular

I have googled for this problem and I found a lot of links which couldn't help me solve my problem. All I want to do is to send forms data to the controller. it goes to the controller but the data is not present in there.

here are my codes:

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {AsyncRoute, Router, RouteDefinition, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, Location, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteParams} from "angular2/router";
import {CitiesComponent} from "./components/cities.component";
import { CitiesService } from './components/cities.service';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
declare var System: any;

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "/app/app.html",
    providers: [CitiesService, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public routes: RouteDefinition[] = null;

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private location: Location) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.routes === null) {
            this.routes = [
                new AsyncRoute({
                    path: "/City",
                    name: "City",
                    loader: () => System.import("app/components/cities.component").then(c => c["CitiesComponent"])
                })
            ];

            this.router.config(this.routes);
        }
    }



    getLinkStyle(route: RouteDefinition) {
        return this.location.path().indexOf(route.path) > -1;
    }
}
```

cities.ts

```
export interface ICities {
    Id: string;
    State: string;
    Title: string;
}
```

cities.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import { FORM_DIRECTIVES }    from 'angular2/common';
import { RouteParams, Router } from 'angular2/router';
import { ICities } from './cities';
import { CitiesService } from './cities.service';
@Component({
    selector: "cities", 
    templateUrl: "/partial/cities",
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class CitiesComponent implements OnInit {
    public City: ICities;
    cities: ICities[];
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(private _citiesService: CitiesService, private _router: Router,
        private _routeParams: RouteParams) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._citiesService.getCities()
            .subscribe(
            cities => this.cities = cities,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        //this.message = "anything!"
    }

    onSubmit(form: ICities): void {
        console.log('you submitted value 23:', form); 
        this._citiesService.addCity(form);
    }
}
```

cities.services.ts

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, Request} from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ICities } from './cities';

@Injectable()
export class CitiesService {
    private _citiesInsert = '/Cities/CitiesInsert';
    private _citiesList = '/Cities/GetCities';

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    getCities(): Observable<ICities[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._citiesList)
            .map((response: Response) => <ICities[]>response.json())
            .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    addCity(city: ICities) {
       let body = JSON.stringify({ city });
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        //let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        var url = '/Cities/CitiesInsert';
        this._http.post(this._citiesInsert, JSON.stringify(city), headers)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError)
            .subscribe(
                (res2) => {
                    console.log('subsribe %o', res2)
                }
            );
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        alert("extract data: " + body);
        return body.data || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        // in a real world app, we may send the server to some remote logging infrastructure
        // instead of just logging it to the console
        alert("error: " + error);
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }
}
```

cities.cshtml

```
 <cities>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="portlet box blue ">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <i class="fa fa-gift"></i> مشخصات
                    </div>
                    <div class="tools">
                        <a title="" data-original-title="" href="" class="collapse"> </a>
                        <a title="" data-original-title="" href="#portlet-config" data-toggle="modal" class="config"> </a>
                        <a title="" data-original-title="" href="" class="reload"> </a>
                        <a title="" data-original-title="" href="" class="remove"> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="portlet-body form">
                    <form role="form" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.value)"  >
                        <div class="form-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>وضعیت</label>
                                        <select ngControl="State" class="form-control input-small selectpicker">
                                            <option value="ACTIVATED" selected="selected">فعال</option>
                                            <option value="DEACTIVE">غیرفعال</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>عنوان</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                            </span>
                                            <input class="form-control" ngControl ="Title" placeholder="عنوان شهر" type="text">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-actions right">
                            <button class="btn">
                                <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> صرفنظر
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn green" type="submit">
                                <i class="fa fa-save"></i> ذخیره
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="portlet mt-element-ribbon light portlet-fit ">
                        <div class="ribbon ribbon-right ribbon-clip ribbon-shadow ribbon-border-dash-hor ribbon-color-success uppercase">
                            <div class="ribbon-sub ribbon-clip ribbon-right"></div> لیست اطلاعات
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <div class="caption">
                                <i class="icon-layers font-green"></i>
                                <span class="caption-subject font-green bold uppercase">شهرها</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body"> 
                            <div class='table-responsive'>
                                <table class='table' *ngIf='cities && cities.length'>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                Title
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr *ngFor='#city of cities'>
                                            <td>{{ city.Title }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </cities>
```

CitiesController.cs

[HttpPost]

```
public void CitiesInsert(Cities city)
{
    Console.Write(city);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="loginForm"  (submit)="doLogin($event)"
```

and in your component

```
 doLogin(event) {
    console.log(this.loginForm.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```